# groupby by max of column and returns the complete row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 5 different columns. My actual problem is groupby a specific field with a max() and return the row that fulfils this condition.

Example (I put the code and a print-screen of the data frames):

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,2),  1240, 1234, 12],\
      [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,2), 1250, 1235, 13], 
      [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,3), 1230, 1235, 12],
      [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,3), 1240, 1235, 13],
      [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,4), 1240, 1235, 12],
      [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,5), 1240, 1235, 13],
      [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,5), 1240, 1233, 11],
      [datetime(2005,1,1), datetime(2005,1,6), 1240, 1235, 14]], \
     columns=['quote_date', 'expiration', 'strike', 'price', 'var']).set_index(['quote_date', 'expiration', 'strike'])
```

[image]

If I groupby by *strike*, I will get only the *quote_date*, *expiration* and *strike*:

```
A.reset_index().groupby(by = ['quote_date', 'expiration'])['strike'].max()
```

[image]

The goal is to obtain the following dataframe:

[image]

Comment: Only replace your line with `A.reset_index().groupby(by = ['quote_date', 'expiration'])['strike', 'price', 'var'].max()`

Comment: This is not correct because it returns all the maxima in every column by the groupby. We want to have the row where the maximum is in a specific column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) working with default indices, so necessary first step [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
A = A.reset_index()
df = A.loc[A.groupby(by = ['quote_date', 'expiration'])['strike'].idxmax()]
print (df)
  quote_date expiration  strike  price  var
1 2005-01-01 2005-01-02    1250   1235   13
3 2005-01-01 2005-01-03    1240   1235   13
4 2005-01-01 2005-01-04    1240   1235   12
5 2005-01-01 2005-01-05    1240   1235   13
7 2005-01-01 2005-01-06    1240   1235   14
```

And for `MultiIndex` add [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
A = A.reset_index()
df = (A.loc[A.groupby(by = ['quote_date', 'expiration'])['strike'].idxmax()]
       .set_index(['quote_date','expiration']))
print (df)
                       strike  price  var
quote_date expiration                    
2005-01-01 2005-01-02    1250   1235   13
           2005-01-03    1240   1235   13
           2005-01-04    1240   1235   12
           2005-01-05    1240   1235   13
           2005-01-06    1240   1235   14
```

Another solution:

```
df = (A.sort_values('var', ascending=False)
       .reset_index(level=['strike'])
       .groupby(by = ['quote_date', 'expiration'])
       .first()
       )
print (df)
                       strike  price  var
quote_date expiration                    
2005-01-01 2005-01-02    1250   1235   13
           2005-01-03    1240   1235   13
           2005-01-04    1240   1235   12
           2005-01-05    1240   1235   13
           2005-01-06    1240   1235   14
```

Comment: It works perfectly. However, for very big dataframes, this process is very slow.

Comment: @NunodeSousa - What about `A.sort_values('var', ascending=False).reset_index().drop_duplicates(['quote_date','expiration'])` ?

Comment: This one is much faster and a very clever solution.